# Select from multiple table (passed by another select)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, dynamic-sql

**Question updated.**

What I want to achive is to get list of new tables which are `empty` or `null` in `description` field. (new tables means with prefix new_) and all tables have description field.

Table definition:

```
create table topic (id int, description varchar(255));
create table comment (id int, description varchar(255));
create table author (id int, description varchar(255));
create table new_topic (id int, description varchar(255));
create table new_comment (id int, description varchar(255));
create table new_author (id int, description varchar(255));
```

Sample data and description:

```
insert into new_topic (id, description) values (1, null);
insert into new_topic (id, description) values (2, 'This is topic description');
insert into new_comment (id, description) values (1, null);
insert into new_comment (id, description) values (2, null);
insert into new_author (id, description) values (1, 'This is casual first author.');
insert into new_author (id, description) values (2, 'This is casual second author.');
```

Like you can notice on my example ideal output for my sample data would've be:

```
table_name:
new_topic
new_comment
```

My actual solution works, but I need to manually add tables and I make a lot of repetitions.

```
select  distinct 'new_topic' as table_name
from new_topic where description is null
select distinct 'new_comment' as table_name
from new_comment where description is null
select  distinct 'new_author' as table_name
from new_author where description is null
```

And output of my solution is like below:

```
table_name
new_topic
table_name
new_comment
table_name
```

I also created SELECT to get all new tables:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'new_%' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Which could've be an entry point for my previous select, but I don't know how to connect those two.

Also my solution is avaiable on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=45a8deb29fb7f7951803b7b8f63b5af3)

Comment: Do you really have a column in all those tables named "column_name". What you are describing requires dynamic sql. But in reality this has all the tell tale signs of an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL to make this more "dynamic".

Comment: I agree with Sean that this might be an xy problem. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve here? Your initial solution might be a wrong start.

Comment: @SeanLange yeah I have in all tables column "column_name".

Comment: Well I still say something went horribly wrong in the design phase. But to help you we need some actual details. Table definitions, sample data, desired output. You know the basic things that any question needs so others can solve the problem.

Comment: @SeanLange sorry, I'll update my answer asap.

Comment: @SeanLange updated. Please feel free to comment if I missed something.

Comment: Your output makes no sense at all. You are selecting distinct strings, that has nothing to do with the contents of the table. I can't wrap my head around whatever it is you are trying to do here.

Comment: My output returns 3 tables instead of one because I have 3 selects, but the result output is similar to expected. And I can select strings instead of table contents as long as result will be similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I think I understand what you are after. Yes this requires dynamic sql. Also, please note that your query to find all tables with a name like new_ is not quite right. The underscore is a wildcard pattern check. So that would return a table named "news" when you don't want it to. Wrap the underscore in square brackets to solve this. Here is how I would go about this type of query. The comments in the code should explain this.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = '' --this must be initialized to an empty string for this to work.

select @SQL = @SQL + 'select distinct TableName = ''' + t.name + ''' from ' + quotename(t.name) + ' where description is null union all '
from sys.tables t
where name like 'new[_]%' --need the square brackets because the underscore is a wildcard so you might get false positives


select @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10)

--this will show you the dynamic sql
select @SQL

--once you are satisfied the dynamic sql is correct uncomment the next line to execute it
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Can you please explain me why we need this line?
select @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10)
and why there is  len -10?

Comment: Excellent question. That removes the final 'UNION ALL ', the length of which is 10 :)

Answer (score -1):

Could you not just do:-

```
select table_name from information_schema.columns 
where table_name like 'prefix_%' and (column_name is null or column_name='')
```

Comment: Looks like you misunderstood the problem. This is not about tables having columns without a name (which the DBMS doesn't allow anyway, so your query would always return empty).

Comment: Yeah, your solution won't work. Anyway I updated the question.

Comment: A column name can't be either an empty string or null. This just makes no sense.